# Continuous integration of an iOS project in a workspace with Jenkins and Fabric

Tags: ios, jenkins, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have a workspace with multiple projects in it. In one of the project I am using Fabric to distribute my build to beta testers. It works perfectly as expected.

Then I moved to continuous integration with Jenkins. Build is successful. However, Fabric doesn't upload the dSYM file.

I have the following script in Execute Shell of Jenkins

Note: Fabric.framework/run command is added in Build phase of the project

=====================================================

```
ARCHIVE_DEST_PATH="${WORKSPACE}/archive"
ARCHIVE_PACKAGE="${ARCHIVE_DEST_PATH}.xcarchive"

PROJECT=<project>
FRAMEWORK=<project-sdk>SharedSDK

cd ${WORKSPACE}

if [ -f "$ARCHIVE_PACKAGE/Info.plist" ]; then
    rm -r "$ARCHIVE_PACKAGE"
fi

xcodebuild -workspace <project-ws>.xcworkspace -scheme ${FRAMEWORK}
xcodebuild -workspace <project-ws>.xcworkspace -scheme ${PROJECT} -archivePath ${ARCHIVE_DEST_PATH} archive
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

If you're using Jenkins, then you want to add a script such as this:

```
/path/to/Crashlytics.framework/submit <API_KEY> <BUILD_SECRET> \
-ipaPath /path/to/my.ipa -emails TestEmail@fabric.io,AmazingTester@twitter.com \
-notesPath ~/Notes/ReleaseNotes.txt \
-groupAliases GroupAlias,GroupAlias2 \
-notifications YES
```

as mentioned [in our documentation.](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/beta/build-tools.html)

Comment: how about for android? i can't seem to find the path to crashlytics.framework since i'm using the plugin at android studio

Comment: I used the same script, its working and uploading build. but email notifications are not working, its works some time, could you please help me. what can be the reason of this?

Comment: @UserDev I'm happy to help, but would need more info. Perhaps raise this at our support [site.](https://twittercommunity.com/c/fabric) it seems like SO may  not be the best option for your situation.